# Public view getter functions generated for array variables throw error

Tags: solidity

```
contract NumberList {
    uint256[] public bigNumberList;
}
```

An error is generated when attempting to call the associated getter function for `bigNumberList` while the array is empty. E.g `bigNumberList(0)` generates an error. Once I've added a number to the array however, I'm able to call the getter function without any issues.

From remix the error looks like this:

---

call to NumberList.bigNumberList
CALL
[call]from: 0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4to: NumberList.bigNumberList(uint256)data: 0x35b...00000
from    0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4
to  NumberList.bigNumberList(uint256) 0xDA0bab807633f07f013f94DD0E6A4F96F8742B53
execution cost  23744 gas (Cost only applies when called by a contract)
input   0x35b...00000
decoded input   {
"uint256 ": "0"
}
decoded output  {
"0": "uint256: 0"
}
logs    []
call to NumberList.bigNumberList errored: VM error: revert.

revert
The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
Debug the transaction to get more information.

---

As you can see the decoded output above is actually correct but I'm currently not understanding why calling the function should produce an error?

Answer (score 1):

You could define a function that returns the length of the array

```
function getBigNumberListLength() public view returns(uint){
    return bigNumberList.length
}
```

if you need to interact with the array, you can get the length of the array first and then based on the length, you can use a valid index

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access an invalid index from an array.

If `bigNumberList` is empty then calling `numberList.methods.bigNumberList(index)` will fail for every index.